# ios 6.0 new addressbook ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion

Tags: ios, addressbook

I want to ask that how I can detect whether my AddressBook was first accessed by an  app on ios6.0. I have learnt that no matter an app was reinstalled or not , the system only thinks that the first installation an first launch is the first time an app launched. the question is that I want to remind an user to allow the app access AddressBook with an UIAlertView,but this alertview will appear shortly after the system's alertview .How can I avoid this condition. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should basically ignore `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`. It is useless. If you want to know whether you have access to the database, call `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()`.

#### Further Discussion

`ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is said by the docs to request address book access from the user. But it doesn't. I will now demonstrate that `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is useless. There are two situations:

(1) If this is a completely unknown new app, `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is otiose: access will be requested from the user automatically when the app tries to access the address book, so there is no need for `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`.

(2) If the user has either denied or granted access, `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is a no-op! Calling it does nothing; it does *not* put up the access request alert!

So `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is just a bug and should be ignored.

#### A Major Correction

**EDIT** In iOS 6.1, this behavior appears to have changed. (I am assuming that my tests on iOS 6.0 were valid, but I have every reason to believe they were.) Now, however, in iOS 6.1, `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` never causes the authorization alert to appear. The *only* way to make it appear is with `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`! Thus this function is now essential; if `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus` that access is undetermined, you *must* call `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` or you won't get access.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved  it by this way.

```
__block BOOL accessGranted;
- (IBAction)accessAddressBook:(id)sender {
    CFErrorRef  error;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,&error);

    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
//        accessGranted = granted;
        if (!accessGranted && !granted) {
            UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Deny Access" message:@"Deny" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
            [alertView show];
            [alertView release];
        }
    });
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if ([alertView.message isEqualToString:@"use contact"] || alertView.message == @"use contact") {
        accessGranted = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The system already shows an alert when you call ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion()
just augment the system app with your own string.

You should have in your InfoPlist.strings:

```
 "NSContactsUsageDescription" = "Tap 'OK' or this app is useless.";
```